# Pandas df - count sum of row with while statement

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this data example:

```
           0         1         2         3        
2  Text1   1         121       2.600,01  2.600,01       
3  Text2   87        44        0         0,00     
4  Text3   19        33        0         2,00     
5  SUM     6         0         0         2.602,01        
6  Text1   1         121       2000      40        
7  Text2   87        44        0         0,00     
8  Text3   19        33        0         0,00
8  Text4   19        33        0         2,02       
9  SUM     6         0         0         20
```

I would like to count the sum of all rows until a specific `df[0]` occurs - in this case it will be `SUM` - until df [0] is different from `SUM`, let it count the sum of previous lines and write them to the variable anyway for each case - in this case if `df[0]` == `SUM` occurs twice, it should create two variables from the sum of previous lines preceding `SUM`:

```
           0         1         2         3        
2  Text1   1         121       2.600,01  2.600,01       
3  Text2   87        44        0         0,00     
4  Text3   19        33        0         2,00     
5  SUM     6         0         0         2.602,01
```

`var_sum1 == 2.602,01`

```
6  Text1   1         121       2000      40        
7  Text2   87        44        0         0,00     
8  Text3   19        33        0         0,00
8  Text4   19        33        0         2,02       
9  SUM     6         0         0         20
```

`var_sum2 == 42,02`

I need it because I would like to compare the values ​​from the calculated sum to the value which is in the `SUM` row - in the second case the value of the last column of the row where `SUM` is 20 and should be 42.02.

So for this case, there should be 2 variables - `var_sum1` and `var_sum2` (of course there will be more variables if the amount of `df[0] == "SUM"` will be more.

If the value of `var_sum1` is different from `df.iloc [:, -1]` for `df[0] == SUM`, an error should be displayed:

`var_sum1` == first SUM `df[0]` - OK `(2.602,01 == 2.602,01)` 
 `var_sum2!` == second SUM `df[0]` - print something `(42,02 != 20)`

Finally, I would like to count the sum of these `var_sum1` and `var_sum1` to `var_sumX` and compare it with another value

How can I do this in pandas df? Where should I start? In addition, you will probably need df.replace after the last column and then change to float. Is it possible to create conditions for `df.loc` 'normally' - search after `df[0] == SUM`?

For the example of a list I could do it - remove special characters from these strings, convert them to float and count the sums from the last elements of the list until the `list[x][0] == SUM` occurs and save it in variables, so I don't know how do this using pandas `df`. Give me some hints or instructions how I can do it and whether it is possible at all.